# Adding and removing entries to dictionary & set

Tags: python

I'm dealing with this exercise where I'm simply looping through a dictionary keys, adding entries to set and removing entries from the dictionary.

According to the official documentation this code should cut it:

```
import random

BITES = {6: 'PyBites Die Hard',
     7: 'Parsing dates from logs',
     9: 'Palindromes',
     10: 'Practice exceptions',
     11: 'Enrich a class with dunder methods',
     12: 'Write a user validation function',
     13: 'Convert dict in namedtuple/json',
     14: 'Generate a table of n sequences',
     15: 'Enumerate 2 sequences',
     16: 'Special PyBites date generator',
     17: 'Form teams from a group of friends',
     18: 'Find the most common word',
     19: 'Write a simple property',
     20: 'Write a context manager',
     21: 'Query a nested data structure'}
BITES_DONE = {6, 10, 16, 18, 21}


class NoBitesAvailable(Exception):
    print(Exception)


class Promo:

    def __init__(self, bites=BITES, bites_done=BITES_DONE):
        self.bites = bites
        self.bites_done = bites_done

    def _pick_random_bite(self):
        keys = []
        for key in self.bites.keys():
            keys.append(key)
        random_key = random.choice(keys)
        #print(random_key)
        return random_key

    def new_bite(self):
        try:
            this_bite = self._pick_random_bite()
            if this_bite not in self.bites_done:
                self.bites_done.add(this_bite)
                del self.bites[this_bite]
            else:
                del self.bites[this_bite]

        except:
            raise NoBitesAvailable()

a = Promo()
a.new_bite()
print(a._pick_random_bite())
print(a.bites_done)
print(a.bites)
```

What is happening is that it seems as if the `if - else` condition is being completely ignored for some reason.

What I'm trying to achieve here is that randomly pick a key from the dictionary and if the key is in the set named "BITES_DONE", then delete it from the dictionary, however, if it's not there, add the key to the set and delete it from the dictionary.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Just tried this on my machine. It removed 15 from `BITES` and added it to `BITES_DONE`. Is that not what it was supposed to do? Doesn't seem like it's ignoring the condition for me.

Comment: @Kevin   It's working for you ??? Why the heck it's not working for me ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried this in my machine also and it worked fine.  The problem is that you are seeing different `random_bite` than the actual `random_bite` that is removed.

When you call `a.new_bite()`, it calls the first `_pick_random_bite()` and when you call `print(a._pick_random_bite())`, chances are it is different from the the result of random bite in new_bite call.

To simply check the result, you can move the print for random bite inside `new_bite` method.

Something like below:

```
class Promo:
    def __init__(self, bites=BITES, bites_done=BITES_DONE):
        self.bites = bites
        self.bites_done = bites_done

    def _pick_random_bite(self):
        return random.choice(self.bites.keys())

    def new_bite(self):
        this_bite = self._pick_random_bite()
        print(this_bite) # Print the actual random_bite
        if this_bite not in self.bites_done:
            self.bites_done.add(this_bite)
        self.bites.pop(this_bite, None)

a = Promo()
a.new_bite()
print(a.bites_done)
print(a.bites)
```

Comment: You're right, I'm afraid ! As soon as I made the suggested edit it worked ! Jokes on me ! Thank you !